# Arithmetic problem involving summation of terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions

This is the question which i am referring to

> If in an AP , $S_p=S_q  $ then prove that $S_{p+q} = 0 $ where $S_n$ denotes the sum of the first $n$ terms.

My try:
Here I used the given condition  and solved further as follows

$S_p=S_q  $

$\frac{p}{2}[2a+(p-1)d]=\frac{q}{2}[2a+(q-1)d] $

$2ap+pd(p-1)-2aq-qd(q-1)=0$

$2a(p-q) +d(p^2-q^2-p+q)=0$

$2a(p-q)+d(p-q)(p+q-1)=0$

$p-q[2a+d(p+q-1)]=0$

$\frac{p-q}{2}[2a+d(p+q-1)]=0$

this is not what is is required to prove instead we have to prove

$\frac{p+q}{2}[2a+d(p+q-1)]=0$

Please mention where i am wrong.

Comment: I think we need to have $p\not=q$.

Comment: I think i am doing some mistake ,otherwise (p-q) would have even not occured in solution.

Comment: I think you did nothing wrong. I think the question has to have the condition $p\not=q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did nothing wrong.

As you did, we have
$$(p-q)(2a+d(p+q-1))=0.$$
Note that this is equivalent to
$$p-q=0\ \ \ \text{or}\ \ \ 2a+d(p+q-1)=0.$$

The latter follows the claim. (I think we need to have $p\not =q$ in the first place.)

Comment: ya but it is not mentioned in question.

Comment: @KartikWatwani: I know. Consider the case $a=d=1,p=q=2$. Then, we have $S_2=S_2$, but we don't have $S_{2+2}=0$.

Comment: ya may be printing mistake.